# Streaming iLBC encoded file via RTP with gstreamer

Tags: audio-streaming, gstreamer, pipeline

I'm trying to build a gstreamer pipeline to create an RTP audio stream with iLBC codec.  Gstreamer (as of version 0.10) has an RTP payloader pipeline element called `rtpilbcpay`.  Unfortunately only the RTP packetizing is implemented, the codec itself is not included in gstreamer.  Using the reference code in RFC 3951 I created iLBC encoded files for sample audio that I hoped to be able to use with gstreamer.  However, when I pipe those files into `rtpilbcpay` I end up with errors.  I "dumbed" down the pipe to the minimum using `fakesink`, the error is still the same:

```
~/tmp% gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=sample.ilbc ! rtpilbcpay ! fakesink
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTPILBCPay:rtpilbcpay0: Element doesn't implement handling of this stream. Please file a bug.
Additional debug info:
gstbasertpaudiopayload.c(909): gst_base_rtp_audio_payload_handle_buffer (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTPILBCPay:rtpilbcpay0:
subclass did not configure us properly
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

I'm probably missing a crucial part (file format declaration?) in the pipeline, as I was similarly unable to play back a PCMU encoded file (`queue` buffers didn't help either):

```
~/tmp% gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=sample.pcmu ! mulawdec ! fakesink
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFileSrc:filesrc0: Internal data flow error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(2550): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFileSrc:filesrc0:
streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Is this simply a bug or is the pipeline setup wrong (I hope it's the latter)?  What further "glue" elements do I need in the pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed I was missing something.  Once I added the correct MIME-type and some other attributes I could successfully pipe the file into the RTP payloader:

```
~/tmp% gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=sample.ilbc \
  ! 'audio/x-iLBC,rate=8000,channels=1,mode=20' \
  ! rtpilbcpay ! udpsink host=192.168.10.23 port=5555
```